# Wait for an assertion to become true, with a timeout?

Tags: python, python-unittest

I'm testing timing-sensitive code where a condition might happen within some time since starting the test, depending on target's performance. In my case, I'm running a VM and waiting for an artifact to be uploaded. Is there a better way to implement this test?

```
def test_something_happened():
  run_something()
  expected = True
  for i in range(20):
    n = verify_something()
    if n == expected:
      break
    time.sleep(10.0)
  self.assertTrue(n, expected)
```

Comment: This isn't a unit test; it's an integration test. Unit tests should be deterministic and depend *only* on your code, not external resources.

Comment: @chepner you're right - I meant `python-unittest` instead of `unit-testing`. My question is about the use of the library and the related patterns, not about the best TDD practices.

Comment: Let's say the way you tell if something raises an exception. You want to create a mock that *immediately* raises that exception, rather than waiting for the real thing to actually time out. In this case, you aren't interested in the actual upload, just your code's reaction to a perceived timeout.